# Using TensorFlow’s Supervisor

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to run textsum model from tensorflow open source models,
inside seq2seq_attention.py they are using Supervisor to manage saving the model,
the problem is after running the app the supervisor starts by creatin checkpoints and graph ... etc but it doesnt save the model after 60sec as the param given, it took hours to execute the next save , I tryied to remove the global_step variable still the same problem, every time i stop the training I have to resume nearly from the start (avg_loss) . can someone tell me what is the solution ?

the code given is :

```
def _Train(model, data_batcher):
  """Runs model training."""
  with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    model.build_graph()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    # Train dir is different from log_root to avoid summary directory
    # conflict with Supervisor.
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.train_dir)
    sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=FLAGS.log_root,
                             is_chief=True,
                             saver=saver,
                             summary_op=None,
                             save_summaries_secs=60,
                             save_model_secs=60,
                             global_step=model.global_step)
    sess = sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
        allow_soft_placement=True))
    running_avg_loss = 0
    step = 0
    while not sv.should_stop() and step < FLAGS.max_run_steps:
      (article_batch, abstract_batch, targets, article_lens, abstract_lens,
       loss_weights, _, _) = data_batcher.NextBatch()
      (_, summaries, loss, train_step) = model.run_train_step(
          sess, article_batch, abstract_batch, targets, article_lens,
          abstract_lens, loss_weights)
      summary_writer.add_summary(summaries, train_step)
      running_avg_loss = _RunningAvgLoss(
          running_avg_loss, loss, summary_writer, train_step)
      step += 1
      if step % 100 == 0:
        summary_writer.flush()
    sv.Stop()
    return running_avg_loss
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify the duration between saves when you instantiate your saver?
I mean (for saving a model every 15 minutes) :

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=0.25)
```